# What's the difference between "consist" and "comprise"?

Tags: meaning, difference

I have often used "consist" and "comprise" in the same sense because meaning of them seem similar. Can you explain the difference between the two words?

Example sentence; From https://en.dict.naver.com/

1. Your teams consist of individuals with great creativity.
2. The collection comprises 327 paintings.

Comment: The difference is, as your examples show, that _consist_ requires _of_ and _comprise_ doesn't. Otherwise they do mean pretty much the same.

Comment: @KateBunting Why not post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

They do mean more or less the same; the difference being that *consist* needs to be followed by *of* and *comprise* should not be.